# Issues with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vscode-debugger

I am new to `React-Native` and am learning from a book purchased, `React-and-React-Native-4th-Edition`.

However, I am faced with debug issue and will appreciate any guidance here.

I am using `VS Code` and has the following installed:

> Nodejs Version v18.8.0
>
> npm version 8.18.0

Error message as follows:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/node ./src/index.js
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught SyntaxError /Users/andrewtan/React_Native/React-and-React-Native-4th-Edition/Chapter02/hello-jsx/src/index.js:1
import * as React from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at compileFunction (vm:360:18)
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1083:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1173:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:32)
at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:838:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:18:47)
```

The code itself is the typical `"Hello World"` example.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <p>
    Hello, <strong>JSX</strong>
  </p>
);
```

Appreciate any guidance here on what has gone wrong.

Thanks.

Regards,
Andy

Comment: this is react right?

Comment: this is not react native syntax

Comment: This is not react-native syntax, to get started with react-native follow 
[React-native official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)